# Getting SSL Wrong version number when trying to connect with Twitter

Tags: python, ssl, twitter

What's strange is that I've been using this code for several weeks and all of sudden I started getting this error: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:749)
Here is the code:

```
consumer = oauth.Consumer(key=CONSUMER_KEY, secret=CONSUMER_SECRET)
    access_token = oauth.Token(key=ACCESS_KEY, secret=ACCESS_SECRET)
    client = oauth.Client(consumer, access_token)

    timeline_endpoint = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/search.json?q=" + search

    response, data = client.request(timeline_endpoint)
```